# Can I turn numbers into an animation to a rigged object?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I have a file of an array of angles (ie: 127, 130, 10, 360). I am hoping to automatically map these to a rigged joint as angles for each number being a frame. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to do something similar to this?

(also if the solution requires coding is there a java alternative?)

Comment: You probably need to do some scripting here. Blender uses Python 3 for scripting. It's not that hard to read a text file with numbers or do a *.csv file import. (example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python + fix for the empty lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row). Then you need to create keyframes of the rotation for each frame. What does 127 mean? Shouldn't there be at least 3 values for the rotation (x,y,z)?